# How to hide a text with css or js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide

I have this html

```
<div id="body" role="main">
    <h1>Title</h1>
<p>My site is mysite.com</p></div>
```

I have `<div id="body" role="main">` or `<h1> and <p>` on every page.

I want to hide inner text of `<h1>` and `<p>` or "Title" and "My site is mysite.com" on specific URLs without effecting `<div id="body" role="main">` or `<h1> and <p>` on other pages.

Please help me to hide them with css or js?

Thanks

Comment: not sure what you mean. You want to hide those elements using CSS or JS without referencing `div`, `role` or `id` on `#body` and without referencing `h1` or `p` in your css/js selectors?

Comment: Do you want to keep tags `<h1></h1>` and `<p></p>` and just remove the inner text?

Comment: @miko Would it be fine for you to add a "hidden" class to do this? If so I believe we can help. Unless you use JavaScript/jQuery, there's no other way unless using a class of some sort. You could also add it in inline styling but your question doesn't completely make sense. Please clarify further.

Comment: @Michael Coker - yes

Comment: @Commercial Suicide - YES

Comment: I think @MatthewChristopher's idea is good. Just define a `.hidden { display: none; }` class and add it to the `h1` and `p`, although that involves  modifying your html, too - not just css/js. Will that work?

Comment: Oh. Hmm, after reading your edited question, what I would do is add a unique class to `body` like (`.hideStuff`) on "specific URLs" and use `.hideStuff #body h1, .hideStuff #body p { display: none; }` - how about that?

Comment: @Michael Coker - I am just want to remove the inner text on <h1></h1> and <p></p> in specific URL like "thesite.com/secret" only?

Comment: @Michael Coker - I am not able to add class, if I am add style that is will efect to all tag in all page.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide immediate child element's of body:

```
body > h1, body > p {
   display: none;
}
```

Le me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.innerText = '';` to set empty content. Check the snippet below.

Update : To check the URI and only apply if it matches, use

```
var uri = window.location.pathname.substr(1).replace('/', '');
if (uri == 'secret') {
    var div = document.getElementById('body');
    div.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerText = '';
    div.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText = '';
}
```

```js
var div = document.getElementById('body');
div.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerText = '';
div.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText = '';
```

```html
<div id="body" role="main">
    <h1>Title</h1>
<p>My site is mysite.com</p></div>
```

Comment: that code will efect to all page?

Comment: It depends on where you place the code. If need to hide text only on specific pages, place the above code only on the pages where you need to hide the text

Comment: If I am add css or js, the code will load on every page, I want the code just efect in specific URL only like "thesite.com/secret"?

Comment: Why can't you edit the "thesite.com/secret" page and place the script ?

Comment: Don't place the script inside a `.js` file which loaded for every page. Place it inside html page between <head> and </head>

Comment: I just have permission to add css or js and not able to modify the page. 
If I am add css or js, the code will load on every page.

Comment: @miko Updated. Check now

Comment: If you want to apply for multiple pages, you can code like `if (uri == 'secret' ||  uri == 'page2' || uri == 'page3')`

Comment: I have add the code in <head> but not work? what the wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Css display property like this :

```
h1{
   display : none;
}
```

Comment: That code will hide all <h1> in all page!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: none;`

```
#YOUR_ELEMENT_ID {
   display: none;
}
#YOUR_ELEMENT_ID {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: I am don't have permission to modify <h1> and <p> but I am can add css or js.

Answer (score 0):

i don´t like id so i prefer class.

```
<style>
.hide {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

So your html:

```
<div id="body" role="main">
  <h1 class="hide">Title</h1>
  <p class="hide">My site is mysite.com</p>
</div>
```

Hope this will help.

If you can´t change the html class or id and both elements are always at position one and two then use this.

```
#body > h1:nth-child(1),
#body > p:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `h1` and `p` from the display on `/secret/` you can use javascript. Just add this to the bottom of of `/secret/`.

```
<script>
            var target = document.getElementById('body');
            target.querySelector('p').style = 'display: none;';
            target.querySelector('h1').style = 'display: none;';
</script>
```

Or if you have to add JS to all of your pages, you can check the URI and only apply if it matches `/secret/`

```
<script>
        var uri = window.location.pathname.substr(1).replace('/', '');
        if (uri == 'secret') {
            var target = document.getElementById('body');
            target.querySelector('p').style = 'display: none;';
            target.querySelector('h1').style = 'display: none;';
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I am have add in all page in <head> but not work?  I use "check the URI".

Comment: @miko can you add the script to the bottom of the page instead?

Comment: @miko this question covers why it isn't working - the first solution has a bunch of methods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: I am add in above </body> tag, work but just in <h1> first tag not work in other <h1> or <p> tag in same page?

Comment: @miko are you defining `#body` in multiple places on the page?

Comment: yes...  <body class=""> <div id="body" role="main">

Comment: @miko I mean do you have multiple `id="body"` elements on the page? Can you link me to your page where you have this code?

Comment: sorry I can not provide the page but thank you so much for your help and time...

Comment: @miko you're welcome. feel free to give me more info if you still need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use {display:none} style for hide text for a particular tag

H1-1

My site is mysite.com

h1{ display : none}